# Django form fields not visible, just button

Tags: django, forms, post, form-fields

I have several independent Django forms on a page, all work, but at first visit to the page, the forms automatically consider themselves POST, but not valid, so the form fields are not visible at first visit, just the button. Hitting the button will load the form fields (with typical 'this field required' error), and once filled in, submitting again uses the form correctly.  How can an empty form, at first visit to a page, be considered POST and not valid? I have 
default settings for each field (in the model), 'initial value' settings in the view (seen below), I'm using bootstrap and crispy-forms, though removing them does not help.  Everything works, its just the 'POST and not valid issue'.

Example of one form:

```
#model
class dbPara(models.Model):  
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    turns = models.FloatField(default=27)
    units = models.FloatField(default=5)
    rise = models.FloatField(default=2.9)
    rescutL = models.FloatField(default=0.0833333333)
    rescutH = models.FloatField(default=0.333333333)
    LorR = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='R')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.timestamp, self.username, self.turns, self.units, self.rise, self.rescutL, self.rescutH, self.LorR

#form
class ParaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = dbPara
        widgets = {'username': forms.HiddenInput()}
        fields =['username', 'turns', 'units', 'rise', 'rescutL', 'rescutH', 'LorR']

#view
def importParameters(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ParaForm(initial={'turns':5, 'units':27, 'rise':2.9, 'rescutL':0.0833333333, 'rescutH':0.3333333333, 'LorR':'R'})
    else:
        form = ParaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entry=dbPara(username = request.POST.get('username'), 
                        turns = request.POST.get('turns'), 
                        units = request.POST.get('units'),
                        rise = request.POST.get('rise'), 
                        rescutL = request.POST.get('rescutL'),
                        rescutH = request.POST.get('rescutH'), 
                        LorR = request.POST.get('LorR'),
                        )
            entry.save()

    return render(request, 'main.html',
              {'ParaHTML' : form })

#url
url(r'^importParameters/$', 'importParameters', name='urlParameters'),

#html
<form id = "H" action="{% url "urlParameters" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ ParaHTML|crispy }}
<input type="hidden" name = "username" value = "{{ user.get_username }}">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Set">
</form>
```

Comment: You say you have several forms on a page. The view here is only rendering one single form. How, exactly, are you getting several on the page?

Comment: And not related to your problem, but your `is_valid` block is doing things the extreme hard way; you should replace the whole thing with `form.save()`. And then you *must* redirect afterwards.

Comment: try to add form = ParaForm() in first line of your view

Comment: Hi Daniel.  All forms (5) are independent of each other, each with its own set of html (<form>..</form>), view, form and model.